# Unable to run background tasks with Celery + Django + Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, celery, gunicorn

Stack:

```
Python v2.7
Django v1.11
Celery v4.3.0
Gunicorn v19.7.1
Nginx v1.10
```

> When I try to run django server and celery **manually** the async tasks executes as expected.
>
> ---
>
> The problem comes when I am deploying `django` project using `Gunicorn` plus `Nginx`. 
>   I tried running `Celery` using `supervisor` but it didn't help.

---

`views.py`

```
def _functionA():
    _functionB.delay() #where _functionB is registered async task.
```

---

`settings.py`

```
# Celery settings
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

---

`celery_init.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os

from celery import Celery


# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'cpi_server.settings')

app = Celery('myproject')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

---

`__init__.py`

```
# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from myproject.celery_init import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

`gunicorn.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn application server....
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=<myprojectdir>
Environment=PYTHONPATH=<ENV>
ExecStart=<myprojectdir>/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --access-logfile access_gunicorn.log --error-logfile error_gunicorn.log --capture-output --log-level debug --bind unix:<myprojectdir>/myproject.sock <myproject>.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

`myproject_nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen 8001;
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:<myprojectdir>/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

---

`celery worker`

```
celery worker -B -l info -A myproject -Q celery,queue1,queue2,queue3 -n beat.%h -c 1
```

---

Can anyone help me with my question(s) below:

> Why is that when Django is deployed using Gunicorn and nginx the Celery worker doesn't executes tasks whereas  when ran manually it is able to execute the tasks i.e. when ran with `python manage.py runserver ...` .

Comment: The way you run the Django server has no impact at all on how celery executes tasks. The whole point of celery is that it is independent of the django process.

Comment: @DanielRoseman that's the reason I can't think of a reason why it runs when I run django manually. I will try to debug more let's see what I can find.

Comment: Where are you initializing the `celery` app in the code?

Comment: @sp1rs I've updated my question above, you can find the details in `celery_init.py` and `_init_.py`

Comment: Where is your `_functionB` task located?

Comment: I am importing `_functionB` from a custom utils file where it is defined as a `celery shared task`.

Comment: Make sure that you are importing the tasks in settings.

Comment: @sp1rs do you mean django settings or celery settings ? Can you give an example?

Comment: django settings.
Can you tell me where is your `_functionB` located?
It should be in `tasks.py`(extended file), otherwise  `autodiscover_tasks` won't be able to register the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have concurrency level equal to 1 (the `-c 1` in your worker command line). This basically means the worker is configured to run A SINGLE TASK at any point of time. If your tasks are long-running, then you may be under impression Celery is not running anything...

You can easily test this - when you start some task, run the following:

```
celery -A myproject inspect active
```

That will list you running tasks (if any).

Another thing to fix are your configuration varibles. Celery 4 now expects all configuration variables to be lower-case. Read the [What’s new in Celery 4.0 (latentcall)](https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/whatsnew-4.0.html#step-4-upgrade-to-celery-4-0) document for more information, especially the [Lowercase setting names](https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/whatsnew-4.0.html#lowercase-setting-names) section.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will go through it and revert back.